# PyQt5: Где designer.exe хранит настройки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui

Хотел полностью рассмотреть получившееся окно,
для этого удалил просмотр свойств и добавление объектов.
Теперь не могу восстановить.

[image: Вот что сейчас]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В нем нажми View -> Widget box

Comment: Окно самого приложения можешь сделать так: File -> New File -> Create